# TensorFlow: dynamic dimensions for images of variable shape across batch size (CNN)

Tags: performance, tensorflow, convolution

I would like to know how would you approach coding a convolutional TensorFlow model for vision where input images may have different resolutions.

A cheap fix would be to all pre-resize them to a square of a big enough resolution with the Python PIL library to then feed that to TensorFlow. But I strongly suspect there is a better way to do this. Another simpler way would might to use `tf.image.crop_and_resize` already from the GPU, repeatedly.

Another way I thought of it was to use TensorFlow variable name scopes and spawn the same model `batch_size` times on each image separately in order to accept different input resolutions, using sub-batch sizes of 1 for each model copy. I wonder if there would be performance problem at the level of computing time and GPU memory size if doing that.

Another approach would be to pad images to some buckets like for sentence models.

I could else train things with a batch_size of 1 and not all of those model's clones but that would definitively be very slow.

Any thoughts on how to proceed? Any facts about TensorFlow's performance that could assist decision? Any existing code examples? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I thought I did it before but maybe I did something different.  If I figure it out I'll post a new answer with how I did it.

Comment: The problem with doing batch size of one is that it'll take much longer to train but the memory size won't be an issue. In terms of an example if you look at the tensorflow models git repo they have examples where they crop and examples for resizing.